# Outlook Folders - Default Item Type

Tags: types, outlook, directory

If in VBScript (in Outlook 2003) I want to read all folders, I use this code:

```
For i = 1 To oMAPI.Folders.Count
    If oMAPI.Folders(i).DefaultItemType <> 6 Then
    ' <> 6 = Not public
        MsgBox oMAPI.Folders(i).Name
    End If
Next
```

It works like a charm but it does not distinguish between **additional mailboxes** (or mailboxes in general) and **psts**, because they're all of type = 0!

Because I'm using Outlook 2003 I cannot have access to the Store object. Does anyone know how to distinguish between those two types?